# JavaScript - how to return data from subscribe

Tags: javascript

I have an async call which on complete calls a getStatus() function which does some calculation on the received data and then return the calculated data. I am calling the load() function and I want calculated data on it.

```
load(case, start, end) {
  Observable.forkJoin (
    this.http.get('/workschedules'),
    this.http.get('/block?startDate=' + start + '&endDate=' + end),
    this.http.get('/filed?caseId=' + case+ '&startDate=' + start + '&endDate=' + end)
  ).subscribe(data => {
    this.works$ = data[0];
    this.block$ = data[1];
    this.avail$ = data[2];
  }, err => console.log(err), () => this.getStatus(case, 217380, start, end, 5));
}

getStatus(caseId, appId, start, end, capacity: number) {
  //some calculation on all the subscribed data
  return calculated_data;
}
```

I want data on load() function call
eg.

```
let temp = load(12512,'22/10/2017','25/10/2017');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix async with sync stuff.

Given that `http` is async your function does have to return async data (that will be resolved at some point). That would be something like:

```
load(...): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.forkJoin(...) // without subscribe
}

load(...).subscribe((data) => ...);
```

Comment: how to get calculated data on async call.?

Comment: @FarhanAnsari You gather it through `subscribe`